# Update new color in Color Picker Palette

Tags: javascript

I installed a jQuery plugin Color picker: colpick.js  and I don't know how to
set the new color for circle icon in color palette (after refresh the page the element's bg is changed but the circle icon in palette still is in the default color area `color:'003a7d` .it is not updating.)(However,color picker and cookie are working well.)

This is my code:
 html :

`<div id="picker"></div>`

JS :

```
    if($.cookie('body_color')) {
        $('body,.livebgchanger ul li a').css('background-color', $.cookie('body_color'));        
    }
    else {
        $('body,.livebgchanger ul li a').css('background-color', '#003a7d');
    }
   $('#picker').colpick({
    flat:true,
    submit:0,
    layout:'full',
    color:'003a7d', //default color
    onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el){
        $('body,.livebgchanger ul li a').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        $.cookie('body_color', '#' + hex, { expires: 365 });
    }
    });
```

Before (I choose a new color and "body" background-color has changed) :
[click to view image](http://i60.tinypic.com/qox76c.jpg)

After Refresh the page: (body background color has changed but circle icon and color in palette is in the default color area)
[enter link description here](http://i60.tinypic.com/30m2yc0.jpg)

How can I add this option and set new color for circle icon in palette ?

sorry for my english.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hardcoding the default value for the color picker. You should pull the cookie value into a variable and use that to set the background and color picker colors.

```
var currColor = $.cookie('body_color') || '#003a7d'; 
$('body,.livebgchanger ul li a').css('background-color', currColor);          
$('#picker').colpick({
    flat: true,
    submit: 0,
    layout: 'full',
    color: currColor.substring(1), //skip the #
    onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $('body,.livebgchanger ul li a').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        $.cookie('body_color', '#' + hex, {
            expires: 365
        });
    }
});
```